# Performant repeated search in list of 1.5 mio elements

Tags: python, performance, list

I'm looking for a solution that achieves the following with a better performance, if possible:

I have a list of router_port descriptions (approx. 1.5 millions) and a list of pattern to look for (approx. 30000 elements)

An element in the router_port list looks like:

```
['tgn-11-2-ho\TenGigE0\7\GGH-12JH-SE\Te22\SFP-10G\Te22']
```

an element in the pattern_list like:

```
('tgn-11-2-ho', 'GGH-12JH')
```

The rule is, that the first part of the tuple must be at the begin of the router_port element, the second can be anywhere in router_port.

Actually I search the following way:

```
def search_for_pattern(pattern1, pattern2):
    pos_list = [position for position, port in enumerate(router_port) 
                if port.startswith(pattern1) and pattern2 in port]
    return pos_list
```

which works fine, but since it results in 30000 loops throough 1.5 mio elements, it takes a while to finish.

Is there a more efficient way to do this using python 3.5?

Comment: Create a dictionary with the first part of the string as key. Then you only need to go through the elements that are matching the first condition.

Comment: But `[tgn-11-2-ho\TenGigE0\7\GGH-12JH-SE\Te22\SFP-10G\Te22]` does not really start with `tgn-11-2-ho`. Are the square brackets part of your input or not?

Comment: your `pos_list`s are used more than once?

Comment: @Tomalak I missed the quotes (and added them now), in case you ment this?

Comment: Also, is a pattern always one complete backslash-delimited "section", or can a pattern contain backslashes or be incomplete?

Comment: @Azat Ibrakov pos_list is used then to pull some data from related lists.

Comment: @Tomalak pattern1 is always the begin of the port up to the first backslash, but pattern2 can be of any length and position, but it contains only characters and numbers, no backslashes or similar.

Comment: So, can a pattern be as short as `"G"` or is it always the complete `"GGH-12JH-SE"`? Thinking of a secondary optimization here.

Comment: @Tomalak Can't be a single char, since it holds information about cards, slots and speeds, the sample "GGH-12JH-SE" is a good one.

Comment: give an example of `pos_list` usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about building this data structure while reading the router port file:

```
port_info = dict()

def process_port(line_num, port_desc):
    parts = port_desc.split("\\")
    head = parts[0]

    try:
        port_head_info = port_info[head]
    except KeyError:
        port_head_info = dict()
        port_info[head] = port_head_info

    for i, part in enumerate(parts):
        if i == 0:
            continue
        try:
            port_head_info[part].append(line_num)
        except KeyError:
            port_head_info[part] = [line_num]

with open('router_ports', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    for line_num, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        process_port(line_num, line)
```

Now you can do

```
def search_for_pattern(pattern1, pattern2):
    try:
        return port_info[pattern1][pattern2]:
    except KeyError:
        return None
```

Comment: `if i == 0:
            pass` doesn't make any sense, did you mean `continue`?

Comment: @Tomalak So the expectation is, that the lookup of keys is faster than a search for string in a list. I will give it a try and return. Thx.

Comment: Azat Second comment: Yes, I meant continue. First comment: Asking forgiveness in the first case would take more lines of code.

Comment: in your `search_for_pattern` catching `KeyError` is clearer and probably much faster than checking for key in the `dict`s

Comment: @AzatIbrakov You are right. I've changed the code accordingly.

Comment: @Tomalak I adopted your idea to convert the data into a nested dict and by that the number of loops reduced to a 1/10000. So now the run time dropped from 7min to 30sec.

Comment: That's a nice improvement, but it seems still rather slow. Can you try the same thing with a single `dict` indexed by a two-tuple, like this: `info[pattern1, pattern2] = [list of row numbers]`. It would require a bit more memory to store, but maybe look-ups are faster than with nested dicts.

Comment: @mstuebner Also measure the time it takes to parse the file separately from the time it takes to query the data.